# Making 3D maps in ArcMap from kernel density

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, kernel-density

I have kernel density maps which I would like this
[image]

However, my kernel density image is 2D (below) and I can't seem to find a way to change angle of my maps this way or create the maps in 3D like above.

How can I do this with ArcMap?

[image]

Comment: ArcMap isn't the 3D viewer application, ArcScene is. Or you can switch over to Pro, that does both 2D and 3D.